Instant accuracy increase while dice increasing slowly (U-Net)
I am training a model for brain extraction on MR images. I use 2D U-Net architecture and pretrained EfficientNetV2B3.
def dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred, smooth=0):

    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    union = K.sum(y_true) + K.sum(y_pred)
    return (2 * intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth)


def dice_coefficients_loss(y_true, y_pred, smooth=0):
    return -dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred, smooth)

def iou(y_true, y_pred, smooth=0):
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    sum = K.sum(y_true + y_pred)
    iou = (intersection + smooth) / (sum - intersection + smooth)
    return iou


### COMPILE THE MODEL
opti = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
unet_model5.compile(optimizer=opti,
                  loss=dice_coefficients_loss,
                  metrics=["accuracy", iou, dice_coefficients])

# Early Stopping
early_stopping_unet = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',
                                             patience=10)

# Learning Rate Adjustment
reduce_lr_unet = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                              patience=5, min_lr=1e-7)
model_history = unet_model5.fit(train_generator, batch_size = 16, epochs=200,validation_data=val_generator, callbacks = [early_stopping_unet, reduce_lr_unet])

Evolution of Dice coefficient loss:

Evolution of Dice coefficient:

Evolution of accuracy:

My dice and accuracy values are pretty much high but I reckon it's going to be better if I could figure out the problem of the model, if there's any. I tried changing some hyperparameters like learning_rate, dropout rates, layer numbers. I can't increase batch_size higher than 16 then it gives me error resource exhausted but I am using 3060 Ti and I made sure tensorflow uses my gpu. I added batchnorm, val_accuracy won't increase otherwise, for some reason I don't understand. It would be amazing if you could explain. I also changed my pretrained model to others such as VGG16, InceptionResNetV2, and preprocessed input accordingly then finally EfficientNetV2B3 which gave the best result. (I am also using early stopping and reduce lr callbacks)
Why does accuracy increase so instant while dice coefficients go up slow and slow? And how can I get accuracy over being stuck at 0.95?

How do you calculate the accuracy value from your segmentation results?

@simon, I edited the question and added my compile and fit lines. I hope it would answer your question

Thanks for the update, it is indeed helpful! From this, I try to answer my question myself: What I infer from your code is that you are actually using Keras. Keras maps the "accuracy" keywords to one of three metrics automatically. In your case, I guess (I am not that familiar with Keras), this should be BinaryAccuracy.

Oh that makes perfect sense. Let me try.

I tried changing accuracy to binary_accuracy, which still gets stuck at 0.95 for both val and training. 14th epoch and they are both 0.95 and dice coef is 0.8 for training, 0.68 for validation. 150th epoch and accuracy values are 0.9542 while dice coef values are 0.94. Still same thing is happening. Accuracy values have been straight 0.9542 in the last 90 epochs. @simon

I did not expect any change to happen, I am sorry if I misled you there. I just try to understand your problem better.

Yeah, I assumed accuracy would've changed in binary_accuracy but that didn't either. I have 125 images in dataset. Could this be the reason and what can I do if I can't enlarge my dataset?

Let me try to answer the part of your question, Why does accuracy increase so instant while dice coefficients go up slow and slow? I guess this is not a problem/error of your model or implementation. I would say, in fact, it is not a "problem" at all, but rather a property of your metrics:

A (pixelwise) accuracy measures the correctly assigned number of pixels with respect to the total number of pixels. It is thus, in a sense, a measure that values foreground and background pixels the same.
A Dice or IoU value focuses on the foreground pixels only. Notice how your dice_coefficients() and iou() implementations only ever count the foreground pixels but never the total number of pixels in your image.

Now assume you have a segmentation mask with only few foreground pixels in relation to the image size; say, your correct segmentation mask is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]. If your network prediction would now be all-zeros ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), it would already have an accuracy of 0.8 (because 80% of pixels got correctly assigned). The Dice and IoU values, however, would both be zero, because no foreground pixel has been assigned correctly, yet.
The following example demonstrates this with a few more iterations (I used NumPy for calculations, but that shouldn't make a difference):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred, smooth=0):
    intersection = np.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    union = np.sum(y_true) + np.sum(y_pred)
    return (2 * intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth)

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred, threshold=0.5):
    y_pred = y_pred > threshold
    return (y_true == y_pred).sum() / y_pred.size

y_true = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

# Round 1: Predict everything as ones
y_pred = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
print("Acc.", a1 := accuracy(y_true, y_pred))
print("Dice", d1 := dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred))

# Round 2: Predict everything as zeros
y_pred = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
print(a2 := accuracy(y_true, y_pred))
print(d2 := dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred))

# Round 3: Predict one foreground pixel correctly
y_pred = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
print(a3 := accuracy(y_true, y_pred))
print(d3 := dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred))

# Round 4: Predict all foreground pixels correctly
y_pred = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
print(a4 := accuracy(y_true, y_pred))
print(d4 := dice_coefficients(y_true, y_pred))

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [a1, a2, a3, a4], label="Acc.")
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [d1, d2, d3, d4], label="Dice")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

The corresponding plot is

Bottom line: Try to understand and get a feeling for the metrics that you use. If they don't behave as you expect, it might sometimes not be an issue with your implementations but with your expectations.

Thanks for this awesome explanation. May I ask, is this considered overfitting, my case? Should I act as if my model is overfitting to improve my results or what? And still, how come accuracy can be so steady at 0.9542 while dice changes from 0.68 to 0.95?

Regarding overfitting: I would not say you experience overfitting. Overfitting would be if your training loss went down while your validation loss plateaued or increased again (or the inverse for your accuracy/Dice). That's not what you see. On the contrary: your validation loss behaves, in the longer run, just as your training loss; meaning, your model generalizes extremely well. In fact I think your model is quite good already with a Dice above 0.95.

Regarding accuracy: consider y_true = [1 0 0] and (1) y_pred = [0 0 1] and (2) y_pred = [1 1 1]. In both cases, your accuracy would be 0.33 (one third of pixels correctly classified) while your Dice goes up from 0.0 in case (1) to 0.5 in case (2). Again, this is because accuracy and Dice coefficient account for (in)correctly assigned background pixels differently.

Thanks for explanation of both overfitting and accuracy. That's great! I could also make the Dice score up to  0.9707 ± 0.0007
